# Firebase security rule (.write)

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I try to save any user transaction log. So for example when a user creates, updates or deletes something its log is saved under "Transactions".

I am having difficulty to write security rules (.write) on this issue.

For example; if a user called (userKey2) updates a user data called (userKey1) as below:

```
{ "Users"
   {"userKey1":
      { "Name":"Mike",
        "Age":"18",
        "Location":"Sydney" }
   }
}
```

I also add it to "Transactions"

```
{ "Transactions" :
    { "Key" :
       { "Object" : "Users",
         "DateTime: "2017-10-25 10:00:00",
         "ObjectKey" : "userKey1",
         "Type" : "Update",
         "Who" : "userKey2"
       }
    }
}
```

I send update command to firebase together. (For "Users" and "Transactions") to guarentee updating them all or none.

How can I make (.write) security rule for "Transactions" ? Because I want to prevent any data input to "Transactions" without its "Object" and "ObjectKey" really exists in "Users" collection.

But in my example, none of them exists yet (they are both new data in different collections) so I cannot check it in "Users" collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using Firebase database triggers to implement this feature.  The client-side app would write only to the "Users" node.  You could create a trigger that would fire every time that an update is made to data under the "Users" node; that trigger could write the additional entry to the "Transactions" node.

The trigger approach guarantees that you will only write data to Transactions that really exists under Users.  The trigger will only fire when data is added under Users.

Also, since the trigger write to Transactions executes with admin privileges, you don't need to give Transactions node write access to the end client user.

[Here is the documentation on Firebase triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Comment: Yes I checked the docs. These are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.